# How to add the Material design effect to android views?

Tags: android, material-design

I am using `AppCompat` theme to provide material theme to versions prior to Lollipop. When I set a image resource as a Navigation icon or as a Menu button in `Toolbar`, I get the ripple effect (motion) on clicking them. But when I try to give the same icons inside the toolbar, they behave like ordinary views, there is no motion on click. 
How are the ripples created? Is android able to create ripples on all the drawables that I provide? How can I make the ripples appear when I use the image resources in a `ImageView`?

Answer (score 4):

You can create the ripple by simply setting the background for the image in the XML layout.
`android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`

Comment: The ripples are created this way but they spread to a rectangular area. The ripples in menu icons and navigation icons cover a circular area. I want the ripples to end in a circle. That looks more good. How do I do that.

Comment: then your image should in circular.

Comment: The same image when I provide it as a menu icon, provides a ripple that covers a circle. But when I give a the background attribute of selectableItemBackground, the ripples cover a rectangular area. So, it is not related to the shape of the image.

Comment: internally they could  use shaders for the image view to show them in circular format.

Comment: @Kartheen : Then what about the case when a button already has a background set. Say a background of red color. Then how can I add ripple effect to it. As we cannot give multiple background attributes

Comment: You can add the level list drawable containing the your color and ripple drawable.
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
    <item android:drawable="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" />
</layer-list>

Comment: I don't think support library has support for Ripple Drawable

Answer (score 1):

Ripple is basically an instance of the RippleDrawable class. You can create ripples using xml and < ripple > tag. The most simple ripple drawable looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight" />
```

You can find more info here: http://blog.stylingandroid.com/ripples-part-1/

Comment: I don't think support library has support for Ripple.

Answer (score 0):

You can achive that using ripple effect.

Implementation of Ripple effect from Material Design for Android API 9+.

The lib is available on Maven Central, you can find it with Gradle, please

```
  dependencies {
       compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3'
  }
```

Usage

RippleView

Declare a RippleView inside your XML layout file with a content like an ImageView or whatever.

```
  <com.andexert.library.RippleView
       android:id="@+id/more"
       android:layout_width="?android:actionBarSize"
       android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
       android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/more2"
       android:layout_margin="5dp"
       rv_centered="true">

    <ImageView
       android:layout_width="?android:actionBarSize"
       android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
       android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"
       android:padding="10dp"
       android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>

  </com.andexert.library.RippleView>
```

If you want to know when the Ripple effect is finished, you can set a listener on your view

```
 rippleView.setOnRippleCompleteListener(new  RippleView.OnRippleCompleteListener() {

   @Override
   public void onComplete(RippleView rippleView) {
       Log.d("Sample", "Ripple completed");
   }

 });
```

For Code and More Information See this link :

https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect

For some more design :

https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui